# Function gets deleted when running "npm run build" using vite for laravel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vite, es6-modules

I have a javasript file called misc.js.
Inside of it there's a function being exported named cancelSelected, when i try it in dev mode of course it works, but when i try the build mode, vite optimizes the file and removes the function, i can't understand why.

misc.js

```
export function cancelSelected() {
  // Function implementation
};
```

I thought maybe it's because it thinks the function is not used anywhere, but I imported it in the main html file

main.html

```
<script type="module">
        import
        cancelSelected
        from '{{ Vite::asset('resources/js/autocomplete.js') }}'
</script>
```

i also noticed that if i try to write this, the function doesn't get deleted

`cancelSelected = () => {`

but if i try to export it, it says the cancelSelected was not defined, if i the try do fix it adding a const like this

`const cancelSelected = () => {`

vite deletes the function, so i can't understand why my function keeps getting deleted.

Comment: That's how tree-shaking works. If vite can't find the usage, it will remove it.

Comment: What happens if you add a call to the function. The version where you don't declare it or export it is completely different. It's an implicit global that way. Definitely not what you want

Comment: "*I imported it in the main html file*" - vite probably doesn't analyze html files. Put your main module in a separate javascript file (and declare it as the entrypoint), or add *misc.js* to the entrypoints.

Comment: i tried adding this line to app.js, which is the entrypoint "import { cancelSelected } from "./autocomplete.js";  but the function still gets deleted